# What should be correct ownership and permissions for TFTP root directory?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, ownership, tftp

**tftpd-hpa on Ubuntu 16.04**.

I need be able to upload files into TFTP root directory. I already have option `TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create"` in tftpd-hpa Configuration File.

What should be correct **ownership** and directory **permissions** on the tftp root directory `/var/lib/tftpboot`?

A lot of manuals and instructions explain this in different way, for example [wiki guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TFTP) suggests to change ownership on TFTP root directory: 
`sudo chown -R tftp /var/lib/tftpboot`
Another manuals suggest set ownership `'nobody'` on TFTP root directory.

What also should be`chmod` permissions on TFTP root directory, if they ever need be changed? For example, aboved wiki manual say's nothing about setting `chmod`.

Comment: The user which is running `tftpd` must have `rwx` access to `/var/lib/tftpboot` and `rw`access to the files. Look at `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` to see the value of "TFTP_USERNAME" - this should be the owner. And there needs to be global write access to the existing files.

Comment: Should the owner ("tftp") set for user and group both: `sudo chown tftp:tftp /var/lib/tftpboot`? And chmod  need be set to`sudo chmod -R 777`?

Comment: For convenience you should set `chown tftp:tftp` on the directories and existing files, but you don't need to. As I said, tftp must have `rwx`access to the directories, independent of the owner. If you want the files to be created/overwritten via tftp, there must be global write access (to the files and folders) anyway. Files newly created via tftp always will have ownership "tftp:tftp".

Comment: @ridgy I set permission 777 to `/var/lib/tftpboot`, but when  I try put file into tftp dir, I can put it only if  the file with the same name already _exist_ in tftp directory. If not exist, then got `Error code 1:  File not found` -   despite the tftpd-hpa config have option _--create_.

Comment: Did you restart the service `tftpd-hpa` after changing the config option? Look at `ps -ef | grep tftpd`; it should give you something like `/usr/sbin/in.tftpd --listen --user tftp --address :69 --secure --create /var/lib/tftpboot`.

Comment: Yes, command output is `root      2566     1  0 23:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/in.tftpd --listen --user tftp --address 0.0.0.0:6969 --secure --create /var/lib/tftpboot`. Still can put (upload) file into tftp dir only if  I first create empty file with file name I going to upload.